# Get child elements of a Notebook

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, pygi

I have a *Notebook* element and *TextView* elements inside them.  Because the pages on the notebook will be constantly switched between.  I need to be able to have in a variable the currently selected *TextView*'s buffer.  How would I do this?

Comment: Although Sam has answered your question correctly, your question is more suitable at stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Nick, Why is it not appropriate here? AskUbuntu is suggested at developer.ubuntu.com (and informally elsewhere) as a source of help for Ubuntu app developers.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
pageNum = notebook.get_current_page()
```

which will give you the current page number. and use

```
textview = notebook.get_nth_page(pageNum)
```

to get the widget on that page.